# Can deleted low quality questions be brought back after they disappear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions, user-accounts

I have this question ban that has been lingering over me for years here. I recently learned somewhere on SE chat that bad deleted questions (which is a strike to delete now counts as 2 strikes to a question ban) that contributed to the question ban can be improved to receive up votes that the question ban may lift??

Can my long deleted questions be revived?

Answer (score 4):

Although it's widely believed that deleted questions or answers count "more" towards bans, no one except SE knows if deletion counts as exactly "2 strikes."

This has been explained to you before: if you want to try to get out of a ban by improving your posts, you need to edit your posts first, then flag them for moderator attention to ask that they be undeleted.  If you no longer have links to your own deleted questions, you can ask a moderator to give you the links.

But since you've gone through that process on this site before, it's unlikely that your deleted questions can be improved any more.  Probably your only hope is the chance to ask one question every 6 months.